# Using an SVG and Apply CSS from Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, svg

So I've browsed several articles and questions here, but no holy grail.

I have an external file `icon.svg`, and I want to use it in several HTML files and have a different fill and sizes for each use.

I can't use `<object>` from what I gather since it doesn't allow for styles from CSS sheets unless you reference that sheet from the SVG file itself, which kind of defeats the entire purpose.

The only way I found how to do this is like this:

```
<svg class="icon">
     <use xlink:href="icon.svg#symbolid"></use>
</svg>
```

And the CSS applies. But I can only seem to do it if I add `symbol` nodes in the SVG file and give them an ID, which I'd rather not do.

Also, could it be that this might be not supported in all major browsers ?

Any way to achieve this ?

**Update:**

Added tags for javascript/angularjs since the solution was JS based. (see answer)

Comment: Have you considered using inline svg?

Comment: Yeah, and opted not to since I'd rather keep the HTML readable.

Comment: Or injecting the styles into the SVG at runtime using the DOM if you're using an `<object>` tag. (The SVG and container would need to be same domain)

Comment: What styles are you trying to apply? You can simply target each one using another class and use css.

Comment: @RobertLongson That's an interesting approach, I'll might have to use it if there is no other way. Thing is I'm using Angular and I'm keeping my HTMLs free of JS, would be nice to keep it that way :)

Comment: @Obsidian Basically fill, and maybe changing the viewBox so it would fit nicely inside of different containers. How do you suggest I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `<object>` and manipulating it after the SVG was rendered, in a way that would help me change the styling.

To anyone interested in the more technical details, I've written the process [here in my blog](http://omriaharon.blogspot.co.il/?_sm_au_=iVVBMQZ47Nss2nP3).

I've created a directive in Angular to handle it, but of course you don't have to use Angular and could take the relevant parts and use it however you want.

**Edit:** Wrote a bower for it, you can get it [here](https://github.com/OmriAharon/ngReusableSvg).

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION 1 - Using generic css styles**

Personally I create several fill colours and simply apply the class to the svg where required.

**HTML**

```
<svg class="icon red">
   <use xlink:href="icon.svg#symbolid"></use>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon{
  fill:#000;
}
.red{
  fill:#b00;
}
.blue{
  fill:#ddf;
}
```

---

**OPTION 2 - SVG's targeted by unique class**

If your svg has several paths you can target each using other classes.

**HTML**

```
<svg class="icon symbol">
   <use xlink:href="icon.svg#symbolid"></use>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon{
  fill:#000;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
}
.symbol{
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
}
.symbol .path1{
  fill:#b00;
}
.symbol .path2{
  fill:#ddf;
}
```

---

**OPTION 3 - SVG's as background images**

## DEMO

To utilise svg's like images they can be targeted with css and even used as background images in css but each svg symbol would need to be a unique file.

```
<div class="icon"></div>

.icon{
  display:block;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background: url(icon.svg);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

To use the svg as different height and widths simply edit in css using additional classes to overwrite defaults using specificity:

```
.svg40{
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
}
.svg100{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

---

**OPTION 4 - Inline Svgs (My recommendation)**

## DEMO

Place the svg file directly in your html to reduce http requests and improve control.

**HTML**

Place just after your body tag at the top of your html

```
<div style="height:0;width:0;position:absolute;visibility:hidden;">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="symbolid1" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
  <title>symbol 1</title>
  <path ... />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="symbolid2" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
  <title>symbol 2</title>
  <path ... />
  </symbol>
</div>
```

Then you can call the svg's from anywhere using the svg's id.

```
<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#symbolid"/></svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon{
    display:inline-block;
    fill:currentColor;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah so that works and that's currently how I use it, but notice the `#symbolid`, which means I have to use the `<symbol>` in the SVG file. Anyway to avoid it ?

Comment: Yes. This is why I opted to use inline svg. It's cleaner and faster as it reduces the number http requests from the browser. To keep your html clean while coding you can use a user control of template region to store the svg elsewhere in your project.

Comment: Without referencing the symbol id how would you specify which svg to use?

Comment: It's true that it saves an HTTP request, but inline SVG has the downside of not being cached. Regarding the symbol id - I expected it to know how to apply the image as it does if you just use `<img src="icon.svg">` and not having to specify the symbol ID.

Comment: but doesn't your svg file contain many svg symbols? To apply it the same way as images then you would need an additional svg file for each symbol.

Comment: It has only one that I had to add manually, I got it without it from the designer. That's why I'd rather not have it.

Comment: Then its easy. Use option 3 above and set it to the background image of a div. Just like an image :)

Comment: I tried that, but then I can't seem to be able to change the fill and the viewBox of the SVG. Is it restricted? (I tried from the CSS to change the fill for instance)

Comment: Dont change the viewbox set it to the exact bounds of the svg then change the scaling in css using height width. see edits above.

Comment: Oh cool, so scaling works :) But the fill isn't applied, what do we need to modify ?

Comment: Correct. I made a mistake background images are not part of the dom and so cannot be manipulated this way. The fill path when using background images would need to be applied directly to the svg, this would mean a duplicate svg would be required for each colour.

Comment: That's unfortunate :( Thanks for taking the time to lay out the various options.

Comment: Please check out this fiddle. I strongly recommend you do it this way to minimze code and maximize control. https://jsfiddle.net/sskmLwr9/1/

Comment: That's nice, but if I want to reuse across HTML files then I'll have to rewrite that into each file (and then duplicating the code), and also the caching thing.

Comment: If you add the svg div to your body tag you wont need to duplicate anything. Are you not using a master template for the website?

Comment: I sort of am, I got an Angular SPA with an index page and using a `ui-view` for routes, but placing them there would mean that page is going to get really big and with lots of SVGs which will not necessarily be seen. That could affect the loading speed.